# HTML file is not getting visible on browser Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, facet

I have tried the following example:

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[ ]:


# Load UCI census train and test data into dataframes.
import pandas as pd
features = ["Age", "Workclass", "fnlwgt", "Education", "Education-Num", "Marital Status",
            "Occupation", "Relationship", "Race", "Sex", "Capital Gain", "Capital Loss",
            "Hours per week", "Country", "Target"]
train_data = pd.read_csv(
    "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data",
    names=features,
    sep=r'\s*,\s*',
    engine='python',
    na_values="?")
test_data = pd.read_csv(
    "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.test",
    names=features,
    sep=r'\s*,\s*',
    skiprows=[0],
    engine='python',
    na_values="?")


# In[14]:



# Display the Dive visualization for the training data.
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

jsonstr = train_data.to_json(orient='records')
HTML_TEMPLATE = """<link rel="import" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PAIR-code/facets/master/facets-dist/facets-jupyter.html">
        <facets-dive id="elem" height="600"></facets-dive>
        <script>
          var data = {jsonstr};
          document.querySelector("#elem").data = data;
        </script>"""
html = HTML_TEMPLATE.format(jsonstr=jsonstr)
display(HTML(html))
```

I ran it using the following command and got the respective output statement:

```
C:\Users\aims\Desktop\facets>python colab_facets.py
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
```

Where as I was expecting to see the HTML view of the respective code. But got only the above statement as output. Please let me know what I can do to improve and get what I wanted to see.

Comment: You got an `HTML` object returned. Try to inspect `html` and look up for methods that can possibly be used, and instead of `display(html)`, try `display(html.method())` untill you got something. This is just a tip for investigation.

Comment: Got nothing but the same output, amigo. Please can you check.

Comment: Is there a way I can open the HTML from the terminal by changing the above code?

Answer (score 1):

from metakernel.display import display

[image: my result with exactly your code]

This is my result with exactly your code
It might be something in your configuration that doesn't work.

I used the jupyter that comes with anaconda 3

Comment: Please write the essential part which you think can be an answer to what I am looking for instead of just putting a link only answer. Here you might get downvoted for this activity. Please check it.

Comment: I am trying it through the terminal file and not using the jupyter notebook. It is damn slow in jupyter for me. Please can I do it through the terminal and the HTML get loaded on the browser. Is it feasible?

Comment: I don't know with these settings how it would work. Maybe if you call a browser, or a browser driver, but I am not sure.